# Nested Functions - variable is not defined

Tags: javascript

> ERROR: "chromeWindow.state" is undefined here

Can you put me in the right direction?

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse) 
{
  chrome.windows.get(sender.tab.windowId, function(chromeWindow) {
    // chromeWindow is DEFINED HERE
    console.log('sending to contentscript :', chromeWindow.state);
  });
  // chromeWindow.state is UNDEFINED
  sendResponse(**chromeWindow.state**);
});
```

Comment: It looks like the scope is not right. https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/javascript-callbacks-variable-scope-problem

Comment: Function parameters exist only within the scope of the function to which they are passed. You should read more about how [functions in JavaScript work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse) 
{
  chrome.windows.get(sender.tab.windowId, function(chromeWindow) {
      sendResponse(chromeWindow.state);
  });
});
```

Comment: this is how I did it at first ... maybe there is another issue ...will add full code.

Comment: ok the duplicate topic pointed me in the right direction...


it was a synching issue. I added : return true;    
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging